# iOS: Issue shell commands to an IP address

Tags: ios, shell

I have an SSH app on my iPhone ([this one](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ssh-term-pro/id389930222?mt=8)) from which I can ssh into a server and issue shell commands. There is also an app called [Fing](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fing-network-scanner/id430921107?mt=8) which can discover devices connected to your network (not just the DNS-SD ones, all of them). My guess is that this is done by issueing `traceroute` and `telnet` requests to your router's IP (192.168.0.1) and with subsequent requests to other IP's discovered.

My question is, how do you issue a shell command to an IP address programmatically with iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can an ssh library (you'll obviously need ssh details for the server) such as [libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org) or one of its ObjC wrappers such as [NMSSH](https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [tcptraceroute](https://github.com/mct/tcptraceroute) project. It is the implementation of `traceroute` using `TCP` packets.

You have to integrate it with your iOS project. I suppose it wont be a problem as its `C` based.
Also it doesn't require to work with raw sockets as `traceroute` tool does. For using raw sockets in iOS you have to have a root permissions, so in this case `tcptraceroute` might be a solution for you.

Good luck

Comment: Theoretically the age of the project should be an issue, as its a `C` based project.

Comment: It is an issue, because software changes so frequently that it is a huge gamble on my part to spend the time implementing it and assume that there are no deprecations and everything will work just as it did 7 years ago.